# iOS8 extensions - what happens on iOS 5/6/7?

Tags: ios, widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have an application that was developed to support older versions of iOS as well, but I recently started on working on a Today extension in iOS8. Now my question is, what will happen to my app in the store? Will it ignore it and make it iOS8 exclusive? If not, I wonder what happens when a user runs it under iOS 7 for instance?

I have found absolutely no answer to this, has anyone been luckier than me on his research?

Thanks in advance,
Laszlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your extension functionality will not be available for lower versions(iOS7 and lower), However the app still run without any problem in lower versions.It has been explained in WWDC-14 session 217 [Creating Extensions for iOS and OS X, Part 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#217).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, it looks like I overlooked this. :)